# Derivative of $\ln|-\cos(x)|$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I had a Calculus 1 test on inverse functions today and one of the questions asked *"What is the antiderivative of $\tan$?"*.

I know now that the right answer is $\ln(\sec x) + C$, but the answer I put was $\ln|-\cos x| + C$ and I was wondering if that answer would also work. My logic is that the derivative of my answer would be $\dfrac 1 {\cos x} {\sin x}$ which would simplify to $\tan x$.

Can someone just tell me if my answer was right, and if it was wrong what would the derivative of my answer actually be.

Comment: Do you mean $-\ln|\cos x|$? Because that is the same as $\ln|\sec x|$. $\ln|-\cos x|=\ln|\cos x|$, due to usual properties of absolute value.

Comment: Whereas $\log{\lvert -\cos{x} \rvert}=\log{\lvert \cos{x} \rvert}$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $f(x)=\ln|x|$ is $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. So the derivative of $\ln|-\cos x|$ is $\frac{\sin x}{-\cos x}$. This is because the derivative of $-\cos x$ is $\sin x$.

So the derivative of your expression is $-\tan x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=\ln|-\cos x|=\ln\sqrt{(-\cos x)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(-\cos x)^2=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\cos^2 x)$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-2\cos x \sin x}{\cos^2 x})=-\tan x$$

Comment: 1. Why $\ln|-\cos x|=\ln(-\cos x)$? 2. Why was this upvoted?

Comment: The (silently) revised version is correct. Note however that the détour $\log|u|=\frac12\log(u^2)$ (which the three steps in the first line can be summarized into) is not required to know that $$(\log|u|)'=\frac{u'}u.$$ In turn, this holds for the reason mentioned in @Thomas' answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \log{(k\cos{x})} = \frac{-k\sin{x}}{k\cos{x}} $$
by applying the chain rule. Whatever the value of $k$, the derivative is $-\tan{x}$.

Comment: Except that here, a priori, $k$ depends on $x$.

Comment: Yes, although since $k$ is locally constant on the domain of definition of the function, you lose nothing by differentiating assuming it is constant.